# Pass data from App to Safari Web page back using Universal Links in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-safari, ios-universal-links

As per Apple documentation ,[Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) , we can move control from Safari to App using Universal Links.

In my app, when user is in doing some actions in web pages, only for particular action I want to move control from Safari to my App. Then I want to do some action in App and then again want to move control to Safari's web page, from where I had moved control to App , with output data that got generated in App by using web service.

I know user can go back to Safari from App by clicking on breadcrumb button in the status bar. But I want to achieve this programatically.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Questions without a [clear problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are not useful to other readers; see if you can ask a [more specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) instead.

Comment: @binarysubstrate As in Apple Documentation, I have done Safari to App jump using Universal Links. But now want to jump from App to Safari's same web page from were, I had moved my control, with data.

Answer (score 0):

- Just use ***openURL*** in your app to open the web page you want to return to in Safari. The Universal Link will not be in effect in this case, since you're in your app and iOS will correctly deduce you just want to open Safari.
- configuring Universal Links does not require you to include the query part, which means you can still use it to pass data (in both ways)

  - You registered http://acme.com/foo/bar in your apple-app-side-association
  - You can use ***openURL*** to open http://acme.com/foo/bar?data=xxx and your webpage can process the data in the query part of the URL